# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error after removing DNX Core 5 from Project.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to add my old "Class Library" project to Asp.net 5 vNext.

this is what i have done :

First i removed :

> "dnxcore50": { }

from **project.json** then ive added my dll refrence path to it :

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "E:\\Somedll\\bin\\Somedll.dll",
        "pdb": "E:\\Somedll\\bin\\Somedll.pdb"
      }
     }
  },
```

now if i run the project i get this :

[image]

Comment: does the file even exist?

Comment: yes it exist , and class library projects was added to entire solution.
everytime i rebuild whole solution the class library project build itself too.

Comment: Check if Somedll.dll depending on some DNX Core libs